# Magento 2 : How to display customer email on checkout success page?

Tags: block, checkout, magento-2.3

My code is given below

app/code/custom/checkout/block/success.php

```
 class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
  {
    public function getOrder()
    {        
       $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
       return $order;
     }
```

app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Custom\Checkout\Block\Success" name="checkout.success" template="Magento_Checkout::success.phtml" cacheable="false">
            <container name="order.success.additional.info" label="Order Success Additional Info"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

```
 <?php if($block->getOrderId):?>
      <div class="success-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Thank you for your purchase!'" data-role="title">
     <h2><?= __('Thank you for your purchase!');?></h2>
    </div>
    <p><?= __('Your payment has been received. A confirmation of your order has been sent to ');?><?php echo '"'.$block->getOrder()->getCustomerEmail().'"'?></p>
    <?php if ($block->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
        <p class="successmessge"><?= __('Your order number is: %1.', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="order-number"><strong>%s</strong></a>', $block->escapeHtml($block->getViewOrderUrl()), $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId()))) ?></p>
    <?php  else :?>
        <p class="successmessge"><?= __('Your order number is: <span>%1</span>.', $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId())) ?></p>
    <?php endif;?>
        <p><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Check your inbox for estimated delivery time') ?></p>
        <p><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('If you have any questions regarding your order , please contact our customer service department on contact@cii.co.uk or +44(0)12 3456 7891') ?></p>
<?php endif;?>
```

$block->getOrder()->getCustomerEmail();

this is returning error : call to non-member function is null

app/code/Custom/Checkout/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
 <preference for="Custom\Checkout\Block\Success" type="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" />
```

All the things are working well.

but not getting block to success page

Please help me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Why you use preference ? not required